# create file global variables in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my issue is i'm tired of writing:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseTypes = require("mongoose-types");
mongooseTypes.loadTypes(mongoose, 'url');
var Url = mongoose.SchemaTypes.Url;
var mongooseTypes = require("mongoose-types");
....
```

in every single schema file. is there a way of having a module that you require set mongoose, Schema, and mongooseTypes variables in that file?

i could do: var mongooseTypes = require(mongoose-global-stuff.js).mongooseTypes;
but, then i'm defining each variable one at a time and i'm not gaining anything here.

i've only found this an issue with mongoose because of how things are defined.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a separate module (say, 'moongoose-wrapper') like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongooseTypes = require("mongoose-types");
mongooseTypes.loadTypes(mongoose, 'url');

module.exports.mongoose = mongoose;
module.exports.Schema = mongoose.Schema;
module.exports.mongooseTypes = require('mongoose-types');
module.exports.Url = mongoose.SchemaTypes.Url;
```

And then use it like so:

```
var mongoose = require('./path/to/mongoose-wrapper');
mongoose.mongooseTypes.doSomethingWithMongooseTypes();
mongoose.Url.doSomethingWithUrl();
...
```

Comment: i'm guessing that'll have to work as i don't see any way of inserting variables directly from one name space to another programmatically. thanks